# What is causing my nivo-slider to throw the following errors?

Tags: jquery, nivo-slider

The errors being thrown are:

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'live' 
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Its almost like jquery is not being loaded or there is a conflict. However all of my other jquery methods are working. This script was working fine yesterday but something has changed and I'm not sure what.

Here is the url,

http://greenbrierupgrade.tcgdevbox.com

Comment: That's exactly what it was. Somehow an older version of Nivo was loaded onto the server than what I was running on my local copy. You should add this as the answer and get your karma... err uh reputation.

Comment: ACtually I dont really care about the reputation. But I suppose it will be easier for other people to find this as an answer instead of a comment :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated and replaced by [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Try using an older version of jQuery, or a newer version of nivoslider